# Google Cloud: Error w/ "Create a new Client ID" for Service account

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I need to create a "Service account" in order to permit my application to access Google Cloud Storage.

I'm attempting to "Create a new Client ID" --> Service account via the Google Cloud front-end, and getting this error:

> Server Error Whoops! Our bad.
>
> Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using
>   the "Send feedback" link below. Copy the tracking number below, and
>   include it with your feedback. Thanks!
>
> Tracking Number: XYZ

I've "sent feedback", but the error has put a hard-stop on testing, and I don't have a $150/month Google support plan ... so I'm now at the mercy of Google's support system w/ no insight into how long resolution might take.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I might be doing wrong / what I can do to more quickly remedy, short of waiting for Google to respond?

Comment: Still waiting, 20+ hours later

Comment: My name is Nikita and I'm a representative of Google Cloud Platform Support. Is this issue solved? If its still ongoing, please provide your Project ID, so I can create a support case and investigate this further. Regards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily a support request, not a question about programming.